# DRF - API with multiple serializers or repeated serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am completely new to REST and DRF so I apologize if the title is poorly written.

I am trying to make APIs for my existing django app. I have a reached this issue which I am not able to tackle so I need some help.

I have this dict

```
 WORKING_HOURS = {
            'work_type':[
                    ('Delivery', 'Customers can book delivery orders.'),
                    ('Pick-up', 'Customers can book pick-up orders.')
                ],
            'hour_type':[
                    ('24/7', '24_7'),
                    ('Daily', 'Daily'),
                    ('Flexible', 'Flexible'),
                ],
            'days': [
                    (0,'Mon'),
                    (1,'Tue'),
                    (2,'Wed'),
                    (3,'Thu'),
                    (4,'Fri'),
                    (5,'Sat'),
                    (6,'Sun'),
                ]
        }
```

In Django app template I looped over that dict to create fields and then manually save them to a model. But I have no clue how to do that in DRF

For every `work_type` I will have`hour_type` and for `hour_type` I will have days for all of them except `24_7`.

For example like this:

```
Delivery: {
    24_7:{},
    DAILY: {days: {Mon, Tue...}, time:{10:00AM, 10:00PM}
    FLEXIBLE: days: {
                   {day: Mon, time:{10:00AM, 10:00PM}, 
                   {day: Tue, time:{09:00AM, 09:00PM}
              }
 }
```

Then I had same for Pick-up. Now I am not sure how to have a serializer(s) which can present a user with multiple `work_type`s

My problem at the moment is how do I show a user multiple `work_type`s. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I am sharing the idea here for anyone who might come here looking for the answer.

If you have a dict of data that you need to expose to API you don't need to do anything other than just dump it to the view. For that I used DRF `APIView`'s `get()` method. Then to be able to receive update or new dict you do that in the `post()` method.

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwags):
        obj= get_object_or_404(MyModel, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

        dict_list = []
        work_type_dict = {}

        ## process your dict here, if you need to
        for work_type, work_type_help_text in WORKING_HOURS.get('work_type', None):
            #processing...
            work_type_dict[work_type] = {
                'hour_type': something
                'work_days': something(),
                'daily_hours': something1(),
                'flexible_hours': something2(),
            }

        ## then dump that dict like this
        return Response(work_type_dict, status=req_status.HTTP_200_OK)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        display_message = ''
        status_code = 200


        working_hours_dict = {}

        
        received_data = request.data

        ## process received_data  here...
        ## save to model, if needed.

        if no_errors:
            return Response(received_data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(display_message, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```